# System throws Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#

C# program that uses `Console.WriteLine` with format strings:-

On running this code system throws Unhandled Exception Error:--

Here is the stack trace:-

System.FormatException:Input string was not in a Correct Format

```
  at  System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper<IFormatProvider provider,string format, Params Array args>

 at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine<String format,Object arg0,Object arg1, object arg2>

 at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine<String format,Object arg0,Object arg1, object arg2>

 at System.IO.Console.WriteLine<String format,Object arg0,Object arg1, object arg2>
```

How can i resolve it

```
class Program
{

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string value1 = "Dot";
       string value2 = "Net";
       string value3 = "Perls";

       Console.WriteLine("{ 0},{ 1},{ 2}", value1, value2, value3);
   }
}
```

Comment: Side note: when asking a question about why code throws an exception, *always* include the full details of the exception, including the type, the message and the stack trace.

Comment: The answers are correct, but I'd recommend using string interpolation (depending on if using C# 6 or later)...  `Console.WriteLine($"{value1},{value2},{value3}");`  It's cool and all that, but it also would have ignored the spaces that caused this issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated

Comment: @Archer its printing {value1},{value2},{value3} instead of Dot Net Perls

Comment: @RakeshKumar: The exception details should be *in the question body* rather than making the sbuject huge - and you still haven't included the stack trace.

Comment: @RakeshKumar: I suspect you didn't include the `$` at the start of the string literal, which Archer included.

Comment: yes now i found out i missed the Curly Braces which @Archer mentioned.

Comment: No worries.  Like I said the answers below do explain what your problem was, which is good for you to know.  I just push string interpolation because I love it so much :D

Comment: @Archer will look into string Interpolation concept

Comment: @JonSkeet included the Stack trace :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space inside the placeholders is not allowed.

```
// Bad
Console.WriteLine("{ 0},{ 1},{ 2}", value1, value2, value3);
// Good
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", value1, value2, value3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without space in the `Console.WriteLine`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string value1 = "Dot";
    string value2 = "Net";
    string value3 = "Perls";

    // { 0},{ 1},{ 2}" wont work, so use:
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", value1, value2, value3);
}
```

[Online Demo!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBAd1R)

If you are looking to add space before each number, add them outside of the `{1}` like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string value1 = "Dot";
    string value2 = "Net";
    string value3 = "Perls";

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", value1, value2, value3);
}
```

Comment: @RakeshKumar did you try the online demo? ([here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBAd1R))